# Numpy Linear Regression: Scatter Plot Works but Line of Best Fit Does Not

Tags: python, numpy, regression

I am using numpy to perform linear regression on world countries' gender inequality index (x) and fertility rate (y). My scatter plot is correct, and my x mean, y mean, and correlation coefficient seem correct (seem because I would rather not calculate them by hand for 161 data points), but my intercept and slope are wrong, predicting between -13 and 19 children per woman (when the real data is between 1 and 7 children per woman). Which makes me think that my covariance and variance are wrong. Because I am using numpy to calculate them and am not keen on calculating them by hand, I don't know what numpy is doing "under the hood." Here is my code. I have tried checking my data and using print statements to isolate the problems.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_csv("GII Data.csv")
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df, "\n")

xmean = np.mean(x)
ymean = np.mean(y)

x = data.GII 
y = data.fertility_rate

print(f'xmean = {xmean}')
print(f'ymean = {ymean}\n')

covariance = np.cov(x, y)
print(f'covariance = {covariance}\n')

variance = (np.var(x))
print(f'variance = {variance}\n')  

# Calculate beta and alpha
beta = covariance.sum() / variance.sum()
alpha = ymean - (beta * xmean)
print(f'alpha = {alpha}')
print(f'beta = {beta}\n')
correlation = np.corrcoef(x, y)
print(f'correlation coefficient = {correlation}\n')

ypred = alpha + beta * x 

plt.figure(figsize=(8, 4))
plt.plot(x, y, 'ro')   # scatter plot showing actual data
plt.title('Gender Inequality and Children per Woman: r = 0.78')
plt.xlabel('Gender Inequality Index (GII)')
plt.ylabel('Fertility Rate')
plt.plot(x, ypred)     # regression line
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calculating beta wrong.It should be

```
beta = covariance[0][1] / variance
```

because numpy calculates covariance as matrix, you should get right value